# Why do animals only eat some parts of their food?

Tags: food, ethology, natural-selection

For example monkeys/apes only eat part of a fruit and then throw the rest. Cats (big and small species) only eat some parts of their prey and then they abandon it.
Humans on the contrary leave as few leftover as possible.

What do we know about the parts that animals eat ? and how do we know it ?

Comment: Humans leave as few leftovers as possible? No, they definitely do not. They throw away a lot of good edible food.

Comment: Animals that abandon some food certainly have quite a lot of food at their disposal and they can be choosy and eat only the best. I'd be surprised that an animal that is starving would throw away some good food. If this is the case, it is probably a case where the animal is not adapted to its environment and do not recognize the good quality food as being good quality food.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on hunger. As in comment (@Remi.b), it has been mentioned, an animal won't throw if they are starving.

> For example monkeys/apes only eat part of a fruit and then throw the rest.

Monkeys and apes can differentiate between good and bad part of the fruits. So, they eat what they can and if the color looks different (or however they differentiate them) they will throw the rest of them.

> Cats (big and small species) only eat some parts of their prey and then they abandon it.

Cats in general are very picky eaters. They actually have a very short digestive tract, so, they need something easy to breakdown into energy rather than complex processes of digestion. Their main food consist of meat, they leave the inner organs as such.

Source:

1. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Wikijunior:Big_Cats/Complete_Edition
2. http://bigcatrescue.org/feed-cats/

[image]

[image]

Image Source:

1. http://wordpress.as.edu.au/rspiers/2013/05/22/comparing-animals-digestive-systems/
2. http://cats56971.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/eating-habits-of-a-african-lion/